# How do I get the form field value?

Tags: forms

The question is clear from the title itself :

I have tried :

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
          $form_state->getValue('field_p_fqdn');
          $form['field_p_fqdn']['und']['#default_value'];
}
```

where **`field_p_fqdn`** is my field name .But both didnt worked . Any idea ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending the field type, it could be:

For exemple for plain text:

```
$form['field_p_cert_fqdn']['widget'][0]['value']['#default_value']
```

or

```
$form['field_p_cert_fqdn']['widget'][0]['#default_value'];
```

or

```
$form['field_p_cert_fqdn']['widget']['#default_value'][0];
```

or for entity reference:

```
$form['field_p_cert_fqdn']['widget'][0]['target_id']['#default_value'];
```

or some other thing

I would recommend you to use the devel module: https://www.drupal.org/project/devel (with the kint submodule enable). With this, you can add

```
dpm($form);
```

in you alter function to get the structure of the $form.

Comment: unfortunately nothing works !!

Comment: Humm, bad luck. What is the field type of field_p_cert_fqdn ?

Comment: Text (plain) (Text field)

Comment: I have updated my answer with plain text

Comment: I would recommend you to use the devel module (with the kint submodule enable). With this, you can add dpm($form); in you alter function to get the structure of the $form.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51438/discussion-between-icecreamjelly-and-baud).